# Why is the Ubuntu Server installation screen turning this blue color?

Tags: boot, server

Lately, the Ubuntu Server installation screen on some hardware has turned this blue color, and the data fields are white with white letters, making it impossible to see what is being typed. What to do to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that, on the affected hardware, you have a problem with the graphics system and that this isnt Ubuntu-specific as an issue.

Comment: Have you tried: `Control + T` or  `F4` keyboard shortcodes for: *Toggle rich mode (colour, Unicode) on and off* [Reference](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-operate-the-server-installer/16689)

Comment: Control +T or F4 didn't work.